# Bash - duplicate lines with different values

Tags: awk, sed, duplicates

In Bash I have a file with following content:

```
05-24-2021,DIS,HostXYZ,   ,,No connection possible,
05-24-2021,DIS,HostABC,BWV ,No connection possible,
06-18-2021,SID,HostWER,SE1  ,No connection possible,
06-18-2021,SID,"Host1:32115,Host2:32115",  ,SOME TEXT,
06-18-2021,SID,HostZZZ,  ,,
06-18-2021,SID,"Host3:32115,Host4:32115",  ,ALSO SOME TEXT,
```

I want to search for a method to duplicate a line with 2 given hosts in it and separate them in 2 lines as follows:

```
05-24-2021,DIS,HostXYZ,   ,,No connection possible
05-24-2021,DIS,HostABC,BWV ,No connection possible,
06-18-2021,SID,HostWER,SE1  ,No connection possible,
06-18-2021,SID,Host1,  ,SOME TEXT,
06-18-2021,SID,Host2,  ,SOME TEXT,
06-18-2021,SID,HostZZZ,  ,,
06-18-2021,SID,Host3,  ,ALSO SOME TEXT,
06-18-2021,SID,Host4,  ,ALSO SOME TEXT,
```

Maybe you have any idea to transform that? I would really appreciate. I tried it with awk, sed and so on. I was able to duplicate (with "sed 's/:/:/p'") at least the affected lines but not to "filter out" the specific values.

Comment: Are there literal `**` in the input?  This sounds like you're just trying to parse a pseudo-csv that has the delimiter in some columns that are indicated by double quotes.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it suits your question.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for `FPAT`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "[^,]*|\"[^\"]*\""
    OFS = ","
}
$3 ~ /,/ {
    gsub(/"/,"",$3)
    n = split($3,hosts,/,/)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        sub(/:.*/,"",hosts[i])
        $3 = hosts[i]
        print
    }
    next
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
05-24-2021,DIS,HostXYZ,   ,,No connection possible,
05-24-2021,DIS,HostABC,BWV ,No connection possible,
06-18-2021,SID,HostWER,SE1  ,No connection possible,
06-18-2021,SID,Host1,  ,SOME TEXT,
06-18-2021,SID,Host2,  ,SOME TEXT,
06-18-2021,SID,HostZZZ,  ,,
06-18-2021,SID,Host3,  ,ALSO SOME TEXT,
06-18-2021,SID,Host4,  ,ALSO SOME TEXT,
```

If you'll be doing any more complicated CSV parsing with awk then see [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Answer (score 0):

It is a really bad idea to try this with `awk`.  Use a proper csv parser.  But, although it's fragile, you can try:

```
awk 'NF<2; NF>2{n=split($2,a,","); 
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%s,%s,%s\n", $1,a[i],$3)}'  FS=\" input
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have at most two hosts per line, surrounded by double quotes, a simple way is to get the duplicates with capture groups:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)"(Host[^":]*):[^",]*,(Host[^":]*):[^",]*"(.*)$/\1\2\4\n\1\3\4/'
```

**Regex:**

- `s/a/b/`: performs substitution of text matched by `a` regex with `b`
- `^(.*)"`: capture the beginning of the line until a double quote (group 1)
- `(Host[^":]*):[^",]*,(Host[^":]*):[^",]*"`: find after the double quote a text describing two hosts and ending with a double quote; capture each host names (groups 2 and 3)
- `(.*)$`: capture the remaining text of the line

**Substitution**: replace matched lines by two lines (separated by an end of line `\n`) beginning with captured text `1`, and followed by captured text `2` for the first line and `3` for the second; terminate each line with last captured text `4`, ie the remaining text of the matched line.

**This answer relies on the sample you provided. It won't cover untold edge cases.**

Answer (score 0):

In `awk`, you can do it as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""} 
  (NF == 1) {print}
  (NF > 2) {
    split($2, h, ","); 
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
      gsub(/:[0-9]*/, ",", h[i]); 
      print $1 h[i] $3
    }
  }' input
```